# Access 2013 + Source Control (Team Foundation Server) workflow

Tags: version-control, tfs, ms-access-2013

Since Access 2013 is not any longer offering direct source control compatibility: how is your workflow to integrate a source code control into MS Access, especially TFS? 
Edit: workflow of access2013 -> ANY source code system appreciated

First thing I think of is exporting all objects into Text Files withe the builtin function SaveAsText which is available for almost every item in your database.

```
 Application.SaveAsText acModule, d.Name, sExportLocation & "Module_" & d.Name & ".txt"
```

I would load, save and maybe even check the plain files in with VBA functions. The question is: is there a better workflow for this task... I really doubt that this is the best way to integrate Access 2013 projects in Sorce control.

I heard of OASIS SVN but I think this is basically the same mechanism I would use.

Please tell me how you manage your access projects

Comment: Did you try TFS2013 MSSCCI Provider?

Comment: this would work for Access 2010 but not for 2013. Source Code Control is not available as an add-in for Access 2013. 
https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-Access-2013-bc006fc3-5b48-499e-8c7d-9a2dfef68e2f

Comment: There is none...  Access isn't meant to be used as an application platform anymore I suspect... Tools like Lightswitch on top of SQL (localdb) have replaced it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/lightswitch.aspx

Comment: Or keep using Access 2007 or 2010 in combination with the MSSCCI provider.

Comment: That is kind of sad. Microsoft encourages and even forces you to upgrade to the newest software product (for example if you are in the "partner benefits" program) but this seems to be a dead end if there`s no source code control support

Comment: Maybe you would like to take a look at [entAscc](http://www.entascc.com). It is an add-in for MS Access that aims to provide the same functionality as the Microsoft SCC Add-In, but works with Access 2013. It is still in private beta at the moment. Reputable SO users can certainly join the beta programm, if they email the address on the website.
(Disclosure: I am the owner of entAscc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use OASIS-SVN [here](http://dev2dev.de/oasis.html) to export all objects in my access database file to be text files.

I then use git, souretree,  etc...

It has worked well for me and has a number of settings that are useful  (eg you can choose to export data, to export table links etc)

It is not ideal, but is manageable and better than nothing!

As you might expect, I use a git project and separate local directory for every access file.

Another option that is recently on the market can be found [here](http://www.ivercy.com/)  "entAscc" now known as Ivercy!

This looks very promising as the source control is integrated into the development environment.  I've not used it, but would like to!

Comment: What disturbs me is that OASIS SVN uses the same mechanism as I described above. Is there any way to automatically inform other developers about changes and is it possible to lock files (so different developers can`t alter the same module in access)?

Comment: After posting last night I found this: http://www.ivercy.com/  I've added it to my answer.  It looks pretty good.

Comment: OASIS-SVN does not support locking and informing, but ivercy.com does.

Comment: looks promising.. I´ll give it a try and if it does well I´ll accept your answer because there really seems to be nothing better out there

Comment: God!  You have to work so hard for an answer sometimes!  let me know how you get on.

Comment: PS.  Also check out these:   https://www.arrow-of-time.com/AXF.aspx        and    http://www.codevba.com/   I've used the latter.  The former looks AmAzing!

Comment: Couldn`t get ivercy working for TFS only for my (also installed) older sourcesafe.. anyway I think it depends on the scenario you have. Just include the two other options mentioned and I think we have a good overview of the source control addin alternatives on the current market

Comment: A agree.  Shame it didn't work.  Did you take a look at codeVBA?  it's nice (but a bit pricey)

Comment: not yet, will give it a try maybe next week though. Thx again!

Comment: @MarcWittmann: Ivercy works with TFS. Here is a getting started guide: http://www.ivercy.com/Support/docitem/getting-started-ivercy-team-foundation-server-ms-access . Our support will be pleased to assist you.

Comment: @HarveyFrench: AXF and CodeVBA look very interesting, but they both don't seem to have any integration of source code control. Am I missing something?